# Cannot edit yforms in Hybris Backoffice?

Tags: forms, orbeon, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

[image]

Hello, Currently working on Hybris6.5 .  Unable to edit yform in Orbeon Form Builder from Backoffice. Shows error like refresh browser and all as shown in image.

Comment: ERROR [hybrisHTTP26] [10.1.238.73] [YFormsProxyServlet] org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to electronics.local:9001 [electronics.local/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
 de.hybris.platform.xyformsservices.proxy.ProxyException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to electronics.local:9001 [electronics.local/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)------------------------ i am using my own localhost in host file but still it is picking electronics.local instead of mystorefront.local

Comment: I see your browser connects to `localhost`. What are `electronics.local` and `mystorefront.local`?

Comment: @ebruchez electronics.local is  127.0.0.1  it is default localhost, but i want to use mystorefront.local.

Comment: It is really hard to tell given this information. I would advise contacting Hybris support.